# How to add a fade in and out transition to images in a Bootstrap 5 carousel?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions, bootstrap-5

I am currently using a Bootstrap 5 carousel, and I want to add a transition that when you click the "next" arrow, the carousel slowly fades out, then fades back in with the next image being displayed. I want this because the images in my carousel are different sizes, so when you click next it just cuts the carousel quickly and it doesn't look very good.

This is what I currently have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Testing</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="testing.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.2/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css">
    <script defer src="testing.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="max-width: 100%; overflow-x:hidden; background-color:black;">
    <div class="container-lg">
        <div class="row justify-content-center text-center align-items-center">                      
            <div class="col-4">
                <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade">
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="carousel-item active img-fluid">
                            <img src = "image1.jpg" class = "img-fluid">
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item img-fluid">
                            <img src = "image2.jpg" class = "img-fluid">
                        </div>
                    </div>                 
                </div>
                <button class="carousel-control-prev" onclick="nextSlide()" type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
                </button>
                <button class="carousel-control-next" onclick="nextSlide()" type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my css -

```
.carousel-item {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.fadeIn {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 2s linear;
}
.fadeOut {
visibility: hidden;
opacity: 0;
transition: visibility 0s 2s, opacity 2s linear;
}
```

And finally here's my JS -

```
function nextSlide() {
    const carousel = document.getElementById('myCarousel');
    const activeItem = carousel.querySelector('.carousel-item.active');
    const nextItem = activeItem.nextElementSibling || carousel.querySelector('.carousel-item:first-child');
    setTimeout(() => {
      activeItem.classList.remove('active');
      activeItem.classList.add("fadeOut");
      activeItem.classList.remove("fadeIn");
      nextItem.classList.add('active');
      nextItem.classList.remove("fadeOut");
      nextItem.classList.add("fadeIn")
    }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: see my `CSS only solution update...` in my original answer which solves the issue of fading in/out sides in bootstrap 5.3 carousel without the need overcomplicating things with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

By default, bootstrap 5 offers fade in/out on slides using `carousel-fade` as shown in live demo below.

But if you want to add extra fade in/out functionality, in your code, you are not using the built in events that the bs5 carousel provides...

You need to use the values passed via the bs5 carousel js events...

See docs here... https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/carousel/#events

See consoled logged events from carousel...

```js
const myCarousel = document.getElementById('myCarousel');

myCarousel.addEventListener('slide.bs.carousel', event => {

  console.clear();

  console.log(event.direction, event.relatedTarget, event.from, event.to);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="https://placehold.co/2560x720?text=Slide1" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://placehold.co/2560x720?text=Slide2" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://placehold.co/2560x720?text=Slide3" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

---

**CSS only solution update...**

After re-reading you question, I think I better understand your problem now.

You simply want each `.carousel-item` to fade out completely, before the next or prev slide fades in.

You can achieve this with a couple of `css` overrides to the transition property to control the duration and delay to the `opacity` transition effect.

See `css` only overrides example below on Bootstrap 5.3 carousel...

```css
#myCarousel .active.carousel-item-end, 
#myCarousel .active.carousel-item-start {
  transition-duration: 600ms;
  transition-delay: 0ms;
}

#myCarousel .carousel-item-next, 
#myCarousel .carousel-item-prev {
  transition-duration: 600ms;
  transition-delay: 600ms;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-bs-ride="carousel" data-bs-interval="1200" data-bs-pause="hover">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="https://placehold.co/2560x720?text=Slide1" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://placehold.co/2560x720?text=Slide2" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://placehold.co/2560x720?text=Slide3" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
```

You will notice in `#myCarousel` div, I am defining these data attributes... `data-bs-ride="carousel" data-bs-interval="1200" data-bs-pause="hover"`.

I have set `data-bs-interval="1200"` which is 1.2 secs, which is the absolute minimum interval time using my css overrides below, so slides never overlap on fade in/out transition. You only need to use `data-bs-interval` if you are using `data-bs-ride="carousel"`.

See comments in `css` below so you know what is happening in these transition properties...

```css
/* 0 second trans delay, .6 second trans duration on opacity fade out. */
#myCarousel .active.carousel-item-end, 
#myCarousel .active.carousel-item-start {
  transition-duration: 600ms;
  transition-delay: 0ms;
}

/* .6 second trans delay, .6 second trans duration on opacity fade in. */
#myCarousel .carousel-item-next, 
#myCarousel .carousel-item-prev {
  transition-duration: 600ms;
  transition-delay: 600ms;
}

/* 1.2 seconds (1200 milliseconds) in total of transition delay and duration in my css above.
If you modify this you need to adjust your data-bs-interval time if your running auto data-bs-ride. */
```

So because our total time of fade in/out transition time is 1200ms, you need to set `data-bs-interval="1200"` as the minimum so `.carousel-item`s don't overlap.

If you want a custom interval time between each auto transition when using `data-bs-ride="carousel"`. You need to add `+` your custom interval time to my `data-bs-interval="1200"` time. So if you want an interval time of 3 seconds, you would need to add `3000` to `1200`, which would look like this... `data-bs-interval="4200"`.

See example below with 3 seconds interval (not including css transition total time 1.2 seconds)...

```css
#myCarousel .active.carousel-item-end, 
#myCarousel .active.carousel-item-start {
  transition-duration: 600ms;
  transition-delay: 0ms;
}

#myCarousel .carousel-item-next, 
#myCarousel .carousel-item-prev {
  transition-duration: 600ms;
  transition-delay: 600ms;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-bs-ride="carousel" data-bs-interval="4200" data-bs-pause="hover">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="https://placehold.co/2560x720?text=Slide1" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://placehold.co/2560x720?text=Slide2" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://placehold.co/2560x720?text=Slide3" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
```

Here is jsfiddle version too... https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/nqkxwcye/